# How can display text on multiple rows and align right?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, word-wrap, right-align

I want to display text in multimple rows and text align right.

I tryed to put it in `JTextArea` with `ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEF`T but punctuation (?!) is not correct displayed.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setLineWrap(true)?

Comment: Yes, the text have auto wraping but align right have this problem with punctuations.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a `JTextArea` for this.

Instead you need to use a `JTextPane` with custom paragraph attributes.

Here is an example that centers the text on each line.

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setText( "one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\nseven\neight" );
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

//  Set alignment to be centered for all paragraphs
SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);

doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
```

Comment: The problem is the text don't have auto wrap [img](http://puu.sh/lMOiQ/f50b3ba62c.png)

Comment: @AdrianSimionescu, A JTextPane does line wrapping by default. You are doing something in your code to turn this feature off. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate the problem, not a picture. See [No Wrap Text Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use html in the JTextArea, Java will display it correctly.
Example:

```
JLabel example = new JLabel();
example.setText("<html>This is the first line<br>This is the second</html>");
```

Comment: But It is a chat post. I do not know where is <br /> therefore I need auto wrap. Text input is a paragraph that must be displayed on several occasions .